# (ROOT apps, tweaks, roms, scripts, hacks) cydia like app for android?

Tags: root-access, ios, themes, scripts, alternative-markets

i was wondering if there was an app for android that is like cydia. i want an app that has a huge collection of tweaks, hacks, roms, scrips, apps, themes; just like how cydia (for ios) has. im not looking for apps like app-toid or 1-market.

Answer (score 1):

Xposed Framework is an alternative to Cydia on Android. <s>but that doesn't work on Android 5.0 just yet.</s> An Alpha-Version was just made available. The installation process is different though and it is still buggy. Only works on Arm7 chips so far.

http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer

Comment: I have xposed but its pretty limited tge only good themeing apps it had were xblast, wanam, gravity box... it doesnt have alot, unless im using it wrong :|

Comment: I can't really comment on Cydia bcs I never tried it, but I know that Xpoaed has 508 modules. And you were asking not just for themes but for tweaks and hacks as well. I could find out how many apps are there for cydia, but Android doesn't really need a hacked "play store" since anyone can sideload apps. Another alternative for the Play Store is F-Droid.

Comment: i just need an easy way to find the mods, themes, tweaks, ect. btw cydia is pretty much an intaller that has a whole bunch of  repository(u add the repos)and the repos have the hacks, mods, ect

Answer (score 0):

I guess [Cyndia App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xcellenzy.cydia) is already available over the PlayStore for Android.

PS: Correct me if, you are talking about something else.

Comment: Lol the tweaks and apps for that is for ios. I clicked on a couple of the featured tweaks and it says compatible with ios (version). Isnt it just for ios devices?

Comment: I think for cydia you should look at this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saurik.substrate

Comment: and another link to Cydia Substrate: http://www.cydiasubstrate.com

Answer (score 0):

There are many app repositories available for android besides the play store. A Google search will reveal them. There are apps on the play store that only work with rooted devices, too. The iPhone is more closed than an android device. For the iPhone, Cydia is the source for alternative apps. That problem does not exist with android.